# How to get the `HTML` generated via DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

The code below monitors the `div` of id `foo` added via DOM and returns the text of that `div`.

```
<script>
  var foo = document.getElementById('foo');

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
        console.log('  "' + mutation.addedNodes[i].textContent + '" added');
      }
    });
  });
  observer.observe(foo, { childList: true });

  var bar = document.createElement('div');
  bar.textContent = 'bar';
  foo.appendChild(bar);
</script>
```

I would like `body` to be monitored instead of the child element `foo`:

```
observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true });
```

In addition, instead of returning only the `bar` text, I would like the return to be the full `HTML`. Like this:

```
<div>bar</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you solved your first problem. The second one is change `mutation.addedNodes[i].textContent` to `mutation.addedNodes[i].innerHTML`.

Comment: Why not just use `Element.outerHTML`?

Comment: @Will The first problem has not yet been solved. The return is `undefined`. My intention is to make `body` monitor DOM additions in each and every child element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `innerHTML`. try adding:

```
console.log('  "' + mutation.addedNodes[i].innerHTML+ '" added');
```